# Parameters with or without 'AS' keyword in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, parameters, variable-declaration

I'm somewhat new to TSQL (mostly MySQL experience). I came across some parameter declarations and I'm unsure what, if any, the difference is when declared in a stored proc with versus without the 'as' keyword:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProc]
    @variable1 varchar(50),
    @variable2 as varchar(50)
...
```

Comment: This means that when you execute your stored proc you will need to pass those variables otherwise it's going to throw an error.

Comment: These are parameters, not variables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct. I updated for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) does not show `AS` as being part of the syntax neither optional nor mandatory.

But, anyway, there is no difference.

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation on local variables shows it but offers no explanation of any differences: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

Comment: @RandyHall Interesting stuff. They might have extended the `DECLARE` syntax into the `CREATE PROCEDURE` header (this is just a hunch).

Comment: The OP posted parameter declarations, not variables.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware of, except from aliasing columns , which `AS` is expected(but not mandatory) , `AS` is optional and more commonly not used in queries . Regarding the functionality , they are the same .

```
FROM Table1 AS t
FROM Table1 t 
--They are the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing variables like this and the code doesn't `DECLARE` them it means that these must be passed through when you execute the query;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProc]
@variable1 varchar(50),
@variable2 as varchar(50)

AS


DECLARE @Variable3 varchar(50)
/* PUT YOUR STORED PROC CODE HERE */
```

When you run the `EXEC SomeStoredProc` you will need to follow that up with the values for `Variable1` and `Variable2` otherwise it's going to error out. `Variable3` above is created within the stored proc so doesn't need to be passed through with the `EXEC` command.

Comment: The questions is about the difference between using and not using the 'as' keyword, not the general function of local variables.